# Batch insert in cassandra using c#

Tags: c#, cassandra, cql

I am new in cassandra. I have to insert 50000 rows in one go in cassandra using c#. I am using cassandra c# driver. i am using following code to insert 
the data in cassandra. Please help me

```
string tableName = "" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tableName"];
            string keySpace = "test";// "" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Keyspace"];
            //string query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (emp_name, emp_position,emp_firstname,uniqueid) VALUES (?, ?,?,?)"; //; "SELECT * FROM "+ tableName + " limit 2 ";
            string query = string.Empty;
            query =
"BEGIN BATCH " +
"INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (emp_name, emp_position,emp_firstname,uniqueid) VALUES (?, ?,?,?);" +
"INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (emp_name, emp_position,emp_firstname,uniqueid) VALUES (?, ?,?,?);" +
"INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (emp_name, emp_position,emp_firstname,uniqueid) VALUES (?, ?,?,?);" +
" APPLY BATCH";

BatchStatement(keySpace, query,
                    Convert.ToString("ashish" + i), 2, Convert.ToString("Mohan" + i), System.Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Convert.ToString("ashish" + i), 2, Convert.ToString("Mohan" + i), System.Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Convert.ToString("ashish" + i), 2, Convert.ToString("Mohan" + i), System.Guid.NewGuid()
```

```
public void BatchStatement(string keySpace, string query, params object[] parameter)
    {
        try
        {
            BatchStatement objBatchStatement = new BatchStatement();
            PreparedStatement statement = PrepareQueryStatement(keySpace, query);
            objBatchStatement.Add(statement.Bind(parameter));
            var session = cluster.Connect(keySpace);
            //objBatchStatement.ConsistencyLevel
            // Execute the batch
            //RowSet row = session.Execute(query);
            RowSet row = session.Execute(objBatchStatement);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Excpetion occured during batch operation method Name BatchStatement error : " + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

I am getting error : Invalid statement in batch: only UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE statements are allowed.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand very well your code sample so I don't know if you are using `SELECT` queries within the batch which seems to be the issue. Regardless, you might be misusing `Batch` because batches in Cassandra are used for atomicity and not performance (most of the time).

If you want to insert those 50000 rows as fast as possible then it's faster (and recommended) to execute 50000 inserts asynchronously with `session.ExecuteAsync`.
Try something like this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (BoundStatement query in queries) 
{
    tasks.Add(session.ExecuteAsync(query));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

For more advanced use cases with many more rows to insert then it might be necessary to control how many requests are executing concurrently but the standard Task Parallel Library already does some of this for you.

The only case where a `Batch` is faster than asynchronously executing all of those requests individually is when you can create micro batches with statements that belong to the same partition but that is much harder to do and it's likely that you won't need that performance gain.

## UPDATE

After you edited your question I can understand the code sample. If you still want to use `Batch` instead of the approach I suggested above then what you want to do is this:

```
var batch = new BatchStatement();
foreach (BoundStatement query in queries) 
{
    batch.Add(query); // you can also add SimpleStatements instead of BoundStatements
}

await session.ExecuteAsync(batch).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the specific question...

Invalid statement in batch: only UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE statements are allowed.

```
"BEGIN BATCH " +
...
" APPLY BATCH";
```

`BEGIN BATCH` and `APPLY BATCH` are the statements which are not allowed.  The `BatchStatement` object takes care of that for you.

As for this statement:

> I have to insert 50000 rows in one go in Cassandra

João is absolutely correct in that what you are doing is a misuse of Cassandra's `BATCH` functionality.  BATCH (in Cassandra) was designed to atomically apply one write to multiple tables.  It was not built to support 50000 writes to one table.  I have seen dev teams inadvertently cause cluster nodes to crash while doing this.

The reason this doesn't work, is that Cassandra realizes it does not have a lone partition to send the batch.  So it chooses a coordinator node, which becomes responsible for pulling and assembling the 50000 results from all other nodes.  That node quickly becomes overwhelmed, and crashes.

Again, João's suggestion of writing your rows asynchronously is the way to go.  The only adjustment I would make, is to add a mechanism to limit the number of threads active at any one time, as a way to protect your nodes from 50k writes of back-pressure.